# Field not initialized when persist object using JPARepository, @OneToMany <=> @ManyToOne

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, spring-data-jpa, many-to-one, joincolumn

I have following entities:
MissionInfo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mission_info")
public class MissionInfo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name="mission_info_id")
    private List<Mission> missions;

    public MissionInfo() {
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

Mission:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mission")
public class Mission implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "mission_info_id")
    private Long missionInfoId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="mission_info_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private MissionInfo missionInfo;

    public Mission() {
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

As I understood in this scheme owner side - MissionInfo

I use following code for saving:
    MissionInfo info = new MissionInfo();

```
Mission o = new Mission();

List<Mission> list = new ArrayList<Mission>();
list.add(o);
info.setMissions(list);

MissionInfo createdMissionInfo = missionInfoRepository.save(info);

MissionInfo mi = createdMissionInfo.getMissions().get(0).getMissionInfo(); <-- NULL
Long mId = createdMissionInfo.getMissions().get(0).getMissionInfoId(); <-- NULL
```

Object tree saved correctly, createdMissionInfo have list with one Mission. 
BUT after saving single mission object (createdMissionInfo.getMissions().get(0))
have NULLs in missionInfoId and missionInfo.

It is possible to tune jpa/hibernate entities that AFTER SAVING will have actual values?
Like this:

```
// should be a pointer to saved mission info
createdMissionInfo.getMissions().get(0).getMissionInfo(); 
// should be a id of saved mission info
createdMissionInfo.getMissions().get(0).getMissionInfoId();
```

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I correct entities according to kostja comment:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mission_info")
public class MissionInfo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "missionInfo", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Mission> missions;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "mission")
public class Mission implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="mission_info_id")
    private MissionInfo missionInfo;

}
```

But when I save using this code:

```
MissionInfo info = new MissionInfo();
Mission o = new Mission();
List<Mission> list = new ArrayList<Mission>();
list.add(o);
info.setMissions(list);
MissionInfo createdMissionInfo = missionInfoRepository.save(info);
```

sql foreign key 'mission_info_id' is NULL. 
And my main question in not resolved:

```
MissionInfo mi = createdMissionInfo.getMissions().get(0).getMissionInfo(); <-- NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

You assumptions are not entirely correct.

- Not the `MissionInfo` is the owning side, but `Mission`. The owning side is the one storing the relationship information. In many-to-one relationships, the **many** side is the ownining one, since it has to store a single FK to the **one** side.
- Your `MissionInfo` class does not participate in the same relationship as the `Mission`. In order to do so, remove the `joinColumn` annotation and add a `mappedBy` attribute for the `missions` field:

  ```
  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="missionInfo")
  private List<Mission> missions;
  ```
- You can remove the `missionInfoId` field from `Mission`. Thsi column is already present due to the joinColumn annotation on the `missionInfo` field.
- If you make the joinColumn non-insertable and non-updateable, you will not be able able to add any relationship data. Remove those attributes:

  ```
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="mission_info_id")
  private MissionInfo missionInfo;
  ```

The persisting code should work now.

EDIT: I thought that the cascade on the `MissionInfo` would take care of the saving. I dont know why it is not being triggered. What you can do to work around that, is to set the relationship data on the owning side, i.e. `Mission`. Then you don't have to rely on the cascade:

```
Mission o = new Mission();
o.setMissionInfo(info);
// persist Mission
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i have some problem again. Please see my post update. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome :)  In my experience, the cascade should have been triggered. Have added a workaround to the question. Please see if it helps.

Comment: when I try to save Mission with setting mission info, i have exception: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: package.domain.Mission.missionInfo -> package.domain.MissionInfo

Comment: Arr, always with the details :) You're right, you need to save the MissionInfo first, otherwise the JPA provider does not have an id for it to set into the join column.

Comment: I need to call miRepository.save(info) before repository.save(o) ? Two times?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, since the cascade is not being triggered, you will need to work around by saving both new entities separately.

Comment: But when I save mission info in my first case (@JoinColumn in both entities) - objects tree saved correctly, and i am calling repo.save(info) only one time. So my main question about nulls. As I intuitively supposed, hibernate will be set values correctly on all object tree after saving. But it have nulls... Unfortunately (

Comment: Looks like I've used up all my powder :) Except you want to keep my answer for some reason, I would delete it since I could not solve the issue.

Comment: I think deleting of your comment is not necessary, because it contains some useful information.